# TFS: Deny access to other teams possible?

Tags: tfs, rights-management

Is it possible to deny the access for a user to the other teams in the same team project?

I have a Team Project that contains 4 Teams:

```
|_TeamProject1
  |
  |_Team1
  |
  |_Team2
  |
  |_Team3
  |
  |_Team4
```

Now i have a user "User1" that belongs to the Team1. 
When that user "User1" goes to the Web Access he can navigate to all of the 4 teams?

Where can i deny the access to the other teams in the same team project?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Under Control Panel -> Collection -> Version Control, you should be able to see the Security section for each folder.  This should allow to to grant or restrict access to each aspect of a team project.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the security at the folder level. You can even give them no access at all and they wont even see the other folders in the explorer.